# Are there any problems using Eclipse 3.6 with the Android SDK?

Tags: android, eclipse

What's the current status of using the latest version of the Android ADT with the latest version of [Eclipse 3.6](http://www.eclipse.org/helios/)?

Previously I've read that there were bugs/problems, and warned to continue using [Eclipse 3.5 Galileo](http://www.eclipse.org/galileo/) for the time being.  Is this still the case, or have the issues been resolved?

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit, but I'm actually asking the question generically, regardless of OS/version.

Comment: what version of the android sdk are you targeting?

Comment: I think he means the ADT plugin, not the SDK, but the android site does not specify which version of the ADT (or if all versions) are affected

Comment: I have update my answer for Eclipse 3.6

Comment: The only issue with the current Eclipse 3.6.1, at least on OS X, but I'd guess every version, is code assist has a bug - editing code is dreadfully slow. A workaround, until the fix is released in 3.6.2 is summarized here:  http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/0f9d2a852e661cba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggestion that developers stay with 3.5 no longer appears, and I've just installed 3.6.1 and am having no problems.

Answer (score 3):

**Update December 2010**: Eclipse3.6 is now supported (as [Poldie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/146043/poldie) [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783461/are-there-any-problems-using-eclipse-3-6-with-the-android-sdk/4620229#4620229)):

- The [Vogella's tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html) is now based on Eclipse3.6 and Android2.3 (Gingerbread)
- The [installing section of ADT in Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing) simply mentions: "For Eclipse 3.5 or newer, the "Eclipse Classic" version is recommended."
- This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520290/correct-install-of-android-sdk-adt-with-eclipse-3-6-1) **lists what you need as dependencies**.

---

(September 2010)

The [ADT page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) still mentions:

> There are known issues with the ADT plugin running with Eclipse 3.6. Please stay on 3.5 until further notice.

Even the latest ADT 0.9.9 is still not yet compatible with Eclipse 3.6 Helios.
And you will also experience:

- [some XML-related bugs](http://blog.restphone.com/2010/08/problem-with-androidheliosxml-editing.html).
- [slow code completion](http://www.listware.net/201007/android-developers/30746-android-developers-eclipse-helios-36-code-assist-very-slow.html)

Yet it must be going to be compatible soon, if you believe [the last "Eclipse Day at Googleplex"](http://www.sdtimes.com/ECLIPSE_GOOGLE_TALK_UP_HELIOS_ANDROID/By_Alan_Zeichick/About_ANDROID_and_ECLIPSE_and_GOOGLE/34584) where ADT was largely mentioned:

> Chris DiBona, open-source and public sector programs manager for Google, put it directly: “Eclipse is the single best way to program Android.

Comment: Thank you for that ADT page reference!  Its probably where I first read to stay on 3.5, but had forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

I use Eclipse 3.6 with ADT and have yet to find any issue with it. I surely never encountered the bugs listed above.

Comment: How long ago was it when you installed Eclipse 3.6, and was the Android SDK already employed (being used previously with Eclipse 3.5)?