# Correct install of Android SDK, ADT with Eclipse 3.6.1

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-adt, android-sdk-2.3

Following the posted instructions for Eclipse 3.6.1 Classic and Android SDK, ADT (where OS 2.3 is the most current) misses a few steps.  Everything seems to work up until the point of loading the ADT in Eclipse.  Prior to doing this add the following dependency sites to the list and enable them so that the ADT installer will pickup all the dependencies (thanks MissKaho for the concise list).

**Eclipse GEF**      - download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates/releases/

**Eclipse EMF**      - download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/updates/releases/

**Eclipse GMF**      - download.eclipse.org/modeling/gmf/updates/releases

**Eclipse Webtools** - download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates/

**Google eclipse Plugin** - dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.6

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that it does work with 3.6.1.

I an answer as a question to allow other stackoverflow users an opportunity to get around the pain I had to suffer to get Eclipse and Android SDK running correctly.  I was amazed at the number of guides, tutorials and posts that left out critical assumptions/facts necessary to successfully complete an action.

So, for any that are offended by my posting a answer as a question, my apologizes (:-)).

If it helps consider my original entry as a pre-answer.

Answer (score -1):

Last time I checked (which was a couple months ago), the Android plugin is only supported in 3.5 (Galileo), not 3.6 (Helios).

PS: You didn't actually ask a question in there.  Implied one, but never asked.  Folks get touchy about that sort of thing.