# Installing Android ADT plugin v9.0.0 on Eclipse Classic 3.6.1 failed

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt, eclipse-3.6

I've followed instructions on developer.android.com carefully:

1. I've downloaded Eclipse Classic 3.6.1
2. I've opened Help->Install New Software and added ADT Plugin site

But install still fails to match all dependences.
I've tried to add additional repositories, but it didn't help.
Are there some clues for installing v9.0.0 ADT plugin on Eclipse 3.6.1 Classic properly?

I've also tried this [Correct install of Android SDK, ADT with Eclipse 3.6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520290/correct-install-of-android-sdk-adt-with-eclipse-3-6-1) - didn't help.

Comment: what is the error you get or what dependency is missing?

Comment: Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 9.0.0.v201101191456-93220 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 9.0.0.v201101191456-93220)
  Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 9.0.0.v201101191456-93220 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 9.0.0.v201101191456-93220) requires 'org.eclipse.gef 0.0.0' but it could not be found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your log message you don't have GEF plugin installed that is required by the android tools.
You can install it from here:
http://www.eclipse.org/gef/

Comment: I've downloaded and installed this plugin, and then downloaded and installed WST from here http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/downloads/ and that helped. The clue is to install all that stuff manually, not just add to the Updates list.

Answer (score 2):

Or you download the "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" version. Android plugin and SDK work fine with this version.
http://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/heliossr1