# Cant Install ADT Plugin in Windows 7H

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

Though this is a common question . I have searched for almost every topic related to this problem . Did everything people say , but it just didn't work . I disable my firewall , disable antivirus . Run eclipse as administrator , But just cant install . Even I tried offline installation . But I failed .  I have tried every possible way .
I tried by using both:

http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Dont know what to do . It seems I can never try android programming on my PC.

My Eclipse version : Eclipse Classic 4.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

1. What errors are you getting?
2. Someone else had some issues with ADT / Eclipse Classic. Read this post [Installing Android ADT plugin v9.0.0 on Eclipse Classic 3.6.1 failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934362/installing-android-adt-plugin-v9-0-0-on-eclipse-classic-3-6-1-failed)
3. Is there any reason you can't use Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers. This will ensure that the java related prereqs are met.
4. Re-install Eclipse. Might be something wrong with the original install or files missing. (Just saying)

--EDIT--
Are you using JDK 7? Some people have complained that this is a problem with JDK 7, and downgrading to JDK 6 fixed the problem. I would give it a shot if nothing else works.

Comment: 1. It says that "Unable to read repository at http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/content.xml."  in both case of http and https .
2 . I have read that post , but that version is not equivalent to mine .
3. Java is running well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you going through a proxy?  I had the same exact issue on my end, and I solved it by correctly entering proxy information.

Comment: Ok... I've seen elsewhere that using a different version of Eclipse, or possibly the EE version, will help.